# TSQL divide one count by another to give a proportion

Tags: t-sql, count, divide

I would like to calculate the proportion of animals in column BreedTypeID with a value of 1. I think the easiest way is to count the n BreedTypeID = 1 / total BreedTypeID. (I also wnat them to have the same YearDOB and substring in their ID as shown) I tried the following:

```
(COUNT([dbo].[tblBreed].[BreedTypeID])=1 OVER (PARTITION BY Substring([AnimalNo],6,6), YEAR([DOB]))/ COUNT([dbo].[tblBreed].[BreedTypeID]) OVER (PARTITION BY Substring([AnimalNo],6,6), YEAR([DOB]))) As Proportion
```

But it bugged with the `COUNT([dbo].[tblBreed].[BreedTypeID])=1`

How can I specify to only count [BreedTypeID] when =1?

Many thanks

Comment: I know "bugged out" is a technical term, but could you share with us the text of the actual message?

Comment: Sorry! Error is:   Incorrect syntax near "="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your problem, although I would suggest you use table aliases instead of schema.table.column.  Much easier to read:

Just replace:

```
COUNT([dbo].[tblBreed].[BreedTypeID])=1
```

WITH

```
SUM( CASE WHEN [dbo].[tblBreed].[BreedTypeID] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: That worked great, I messed it up at first but got it going once I read through again. Thank you!!